# Will adding a new objectClass in ldap get replicated?

Tags: ldap, slapd

I have a ldap setup with one master and two replicas created using this tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-server-replication .

If I add a new/custom objectClass to the Provider's schema, will that get replicated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you're replicating `dn: cn=schema,cn=config` from your provider to your consumers.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that objectClass are not replicated by default if it's not intended by replicating the cn=config.
As main setup DO NOT include the config object, consider that ojectClass have to be initialized on all your OpenLDAP nodes.